# My Mac Mouse has only a left button

Tags: osx

My Apple mouse has only one button (a Left button). Normally I use                   ctrl + left mouse as a way to use the left mouse button but it doesn't work with blender. what do I have to do. Because I can't select anything.

Comment: In my opinion, if you are going to  dive into blender you might want to get a real mouse with two buttons and a wheel... they are so cheap these days. The program is really designed to have more than one input from the mouse. While there are workarounds, I feel that they are going to make the experience of using blender cumbersome and less intuitive. watch: https://vimeo.com/76335056

Comment: You may also want to enable right-clicking under the OSX System Preferences->Mouse->Secondary Click  The Apple mouse is touch sensitive if you have something similar to mine.  It can detect which side of the mouse your finger is on when you click and so it supports both left and right clicking with only one button.

Comment: There is a setting I recently heard of but never used that allows for the middle mouse button to be emulated by left-clicking and holding down Alt.  It's mentioned here.  https://developer.blender.org/D1286

Answer (score 4):

You can set selection to be with the left mouse button :

- got to **File**➝**User Preferences**➝**Input**
- in **Select with** click **Left**

also you can search and reassign all what is related to the right mouse button

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you enable "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" you can hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> and then click to select

1. **File** ➝ **User Preferences** ➝ **Input**
2. **Mouse** click **Emulate 3 Button mouse**

This will not work with the [Left Mouse Select option](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30631/18697).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how recent the mouse is (mighty mouse, magic mouse), it may contain sensors for right and middle click. Right click is disabled by default. See the mouse preferences in OSX to enable right click (aka secondary click).