# Cannot edit vertices, edges or faces

Tags: transforms, selection-tools, 3d-cursor

I cannot edit vertices, edges or faces because of the 3d cursor.
When in edit mode with the appropriate vertex, edge or face icon selected I try to click to select, say a vertex which I want to drag to resize and all I get is the 3D cursor which cancels the drag edit action.

Comment: Are you using a left or right mouse button to drag?

Comment: Im on a Mac with magic mouse track ball.

Comment: You have to use right mouse button to move faces, vertices, and edges. If that still does not work, try going into user preferences to check if anything is changed.

Comment: In general, you may find the keyboard shortcuts G/R/S are easier and faster when you want to Grab, Rotate, or Scale. Not trying to side-step your question, just sharing workflow advice that has worked for me.

Comment: possible dup :    [My Mac Mouse has only a left button](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30621/5113)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mouse button with which you click in the Preferences/Input and change (select with) to Left, it is set to Right by default

Comment: Guys **Many Thanks** for your help! Preferences/Input > set to left did it for my Mac mouse. Thanks Igor, Very grateful for this active and knowledgeable forum.

Comment: Would you mind upvoting me and marking as an answer.